# Is there a better way to move a file to a read only folder using .NET?

Tags: c#, service, directory, move, readonly

I am writing a C#/WPF business application that needs to (among other things) re-organise some media files (audio, video and image files). The application must also run in the security context of the current user and therefore has the same access rights as them.

The application is to be the one place that the media can be accessed in order to stop any unauthorised access being made to the files. My initial thoughts were to organise the media in a read only folder and use a service with appropriate rights to move the files into the read only folder.

The actual application will not have the right to move files to the read only folder because it shares the rights of the current user who must not have access rights to the folder.

At first, I looked at a Windows Service, but thought that communicating with it would be too much of a pain to set up. I am therefore using a WCF service, but while the service setup works, it seems a bit of a waste to have a service that only has one method 'MoveFile'... the application (and users) can still read from the folder, just not write to it.

Is there a better solution of moving files to a read only folder in .NET? Is it possible for instance, to have part of the application run as a separate user just while moving the files to the read only folder(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to **impersonate** the procedure to move a file from your main application ?
You can use the: [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/w070t6ka)

Comment: Thanks @polkduran, that's a much better solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the current user is running the application, then the application should have the same rights. You shouldn't need to move to a read-only folder to bypass the security. You might have to catch Exceptions such as UnauthorizedAccessException if the current user doesn't have the appropriate rights.

Have you tested reading directories and files with different levels of access to see if it works automatically?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. The application moves the files to the read only folder(s) so that the users can access but cannot change or move the files using Windows Explorer. The application should be the only point of adding or replacing the files.